# Defining functions multiple times when using setContentView

Tags: java, android, setcontentview

I'm extremely new to Java and Android development and I'm trying to create a little "Quiz" that has `RadioButton` selections on each view as well as as a next and back button. I am getting the next and back buttons to work but it seems like a very long-winded way to do it. Is there a way I can define a function once and have it work in that layout without having to redefine it everytime I use the back button. I.e. I have `nexButtonGPAbuttonClick()` defined in the `onCreate` but when I get to `activity_main_2_.xml` and set the back button to `setContentView(activty_main.xml)`, I am having to redefine that `nextButtonGPAbuttonClick();` again in that `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`. Here is my .java file. Any guidance would be extremely helpful.

```
package com.example.studentadvisorapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nextButtonGPAbuttonClick(); 
    }

    private void nextButtonGPAbuttonClick() {
        //Get reference to button
        Button nextButtonGPA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button_gpa);

        //set click listener
        nextButtonGPA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);
            prevButtonHoursEnrolledbuttonClick();
            nextButtonHoursEnrolledbuttonClick();
        }

        private void prevButtonHoursEnrolledbuttonClick() {
            //Get reference to button
            Button prevButtonHoursEnrolled = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev_button_hours_enrolled);

               //set click listener
           prevButtonHoursEnrolled.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    nextButtonGPAbuttonClick();
              }
              });
           }

           private void nextButtonHoursEnrolledbuttonClick() {
             //Get reference to button
                Button nextButtonHoursEnrolled = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button_hours_enrolled);

             //set click listener
             nextButtonHoursEnrolled.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_3);
                    nextButtonHoursWorkingbuttonClick();
                prevButtonHoursWorkingbuttonClick();
                 }

                 private void nextButtonHoursWorkingbuttonClick() {
                    //Get reference to button
                Button nextButtonHoursWorking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button_hours_working);

                //set click listener
                nextButtonHoursWorking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_4);      
                }
            });
        }

        private void prevButtonHoursWorkingbuttonClick() {
            //Get reference to button
            Button nextButtonHoursWorking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev_button_hours_working);
            //set click listener
            nextButtonHoursWorking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);                                     prevButtonHoursEnrolledbuttonClick();                            nextButtonHoursEnrolledbuttonClick();

            }
        });
    }                               
});
}
});
}




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in the `nexButtonGPAbuttonClick()` function? The question is still a bit unclear.

Comment: I have 5 questions and each question has a set of options and a next and previous button.  All the nextButton(); function should take the user to the next questions and all the prevButton(); functions should take the user to the previous view.

Comment: It seems like just a new question didn't justify beginning a new activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new Activity instead of calling setContentView. That way the back button will automatically take the user back to the previous screen.